# Definitive list of FlashPlayer bugs for all released versions of FP10?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging

Does anyone know where I might get a list of ALL bugs for currently released versions of  FP10?

Reason I ask is spent a day debugging one very HUGE issue with the activeX(IE) only version of FP10.02.

This plugin DOES NOT recognize Stage.stageHeight, Stage.stageWidth !!!

What makes this worse is this particular version IS NOT available for download...even in the archived Flash Player versions...so pretty difficult to test for...

Comment: In general, the first troubleshooting step should be "does the bug happen when you use the latest version?"

Answer (score 3):

Adobe has a public bug tracker that you can register for and browse:

http://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's something very specific, just make sure you wait a few moments (usually a frame is enough) before reading the stage size, this has been an issue on ie since forever.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash Player Bug and Issue Management System: http://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the Stage has been loaded

```
if (stage)
    // do stuff;
else
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, doStuff);
```